# System of linear equations problem - have no idea how to set up equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The area of a rectangle is 9 more than its perimeter. The length is 3 greater than 4 times the width. What is the area of the rectangle?

The answer says the area is 45 square units, and the length is 15, and the width is 3.

I have no idea how to even set up the equations. Any help?

Comment: Let $L$ be the length. Let $W$ be the width. Now start turning sentences into equations. Try it, and report back to us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width to $w$.  Then you can express the length in terms of $w$.
Then you can multiply those two terms to get the Area.
Then add your expression for length to $w$ and double that to get perimeter.
Set your expression for Area to your expression for perimeter + 9.  Gather terms, factor, etc...

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you. :)